# Can I Use a Future<String> to 'Fill In' a Text() Widget Instead of Using FutureBuilder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, async-await, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to better understand Futures in Flutter. In this example, my app makes an API call to get some information of type `Future<String>`. I'd like to display this information in a `Text()` widget. However, because my `String` is wrapped in a `Future` I'm unable to put this information in my `Text()` widget, and I'm not sure how to handle this without resorting to a `FutureBuilder` to create the small widget tree.

The following example uses a `FutureBuilder` and it works fine. Note that I've commented out the following line near the bottom:

`Future<String> category = getData();`

Is it possible to turn `category` into a `String` and simply drop this in my `Text()` widget?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'cocktails.dart';

class CocktailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CocktailScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CocktailScreen> createState() => _CocktailScreenState();
}

class _CocktailScreenState extends State<CocktailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Cocktails cocktails = Cocktails();

    Future<String> getData() async {
      var data = await cocktails.getCocktailByName('margarita');
      String category = data['drinks'][0]['strCategory'];
      print('Category: ${data["drinks"][0]["strCategory"]}');
      return category;
    }

    FutureBuilder categoryText = FutureBuilder(
      initialData: '',
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          }
        }
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );

    //Future<String> category = getData();

    return Center(
      child: categoryText,
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my `Cocktails` class:

```
import 'networking.dart';

const apiKey = '1';
const apiUrl = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php';

class Cocktails {
  Future<dynamic> getCocktailByName(String cocktailName) async {
    NetworkHelper networkHelper =
        NetworkHelper('$apiUrl?s=$cocktailName&apikey=$apiKey');
    dynamic cocktailData = await networkHelper.getData();
    return cocktailData;
  }
}
```

And here's my `NetworkHelper` class:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class NetworkHelper {
  NetworkHelper(this.url);

  final String url;

  Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
      return decodedData;
    } else {
      //print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      throw 'Sorry, there\'s a problem with the request';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `getData()` returns a `Future<String>` therefore I cannot use it directly in `Text()`. In other words, I'm looking for a way to use `category` in my text widget like this: `Text(category)` without resorting to a `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is using `FutureBuilder`:

```
FutureBuilder categoryText = FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading....');
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                var data = snapshot.data ?? '';

                return Text(data);
              }
          }
        },
      ),
```

but if you don't want to use `FutureBuilder`, first define a string variable like below and change your adasd to this :

```
String category = '';

Future<void> getData() async {
  var data = await cocktails.getCocktailByName('margarita');
  setState(() {
     category = data['drinks'][0]['strCategory'];
  });
}
```

then call it in initState :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(category),
    );
  }
```

**remember** define `category` and `getData` and `cocktails` out of build method not inside it.

Comment: Thanks, but my `FutureBuilder` is already working. I was looking for a way to do this without using a `FutureBuilder`. I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible?

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out, @MySilmaril

Comment: Thanks again. This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried it and it works great, but I think I will take your advice and use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: @MySilmaril glad to help, yes `FutureBuilder` is the right way.

Comment: I'd use a RiverPod FutureProvider before using a FutureBuilder any day.  A lot more flexible, and far cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve getting `Future` value and update the state based on in without using Using `FutureBuilder`, by calling the `Future` in the `initState()`, and using the `then` keyword, to update the state when the Future returns a snapshot.

```
   class StatefuleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const StatefuleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefuleWidget> createState() => _StatefuleWidgetState();
}

class _StatefuleWidgetState extends State<StatefuleWidget> {
  String? text;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var data = await cocktails.getCocktailByName('margarita');
    String category = data['drinks'][0]['strCategory'];
    print('Category: ${data["drinks"][0]["strCategory"]}');
    return category;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        text = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text ?? 'Loading');
  }
}
```

here I made the `text` variable nullable, then in the implementation of the `Text()` widget I set to it a **loading** text as default value to be shown until it `Future` is done0

Comment: Thanks for sharing how to do this using the `then` keyword. I've been using async-await so far so this is a very helpful example for me.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your work

Comment: `super.initState();` belongs **first** in initState(), not last.

Comment: thank you, I mistook it. I will modify the answer